# Java Virtual Folder?

Tags: java, system, virtual, directory

Is it possible to somehow create a virtual folder with Java, and hook a bunch of events to it (for example whenever another program tries to fetch a list of files inside the folder, or tries to read a file?)

I don't think so, and I've googled for quite a while but this question has been on my mind for a long time and maybe I'm just not using the right keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 7 has a so called WatchService for directories/files.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Commons' [VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html)?

Wait, when *other* programs try to read its files or folders? You *might* be able to use NIO somehow, but things like this really aren't what Java is good at--it *sounds* like you want something like [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), but if you want this to be cross-platform, good luck with that.